# How can I limit the voltage of a circuit so that it is always between 8 and 15 volts?

Tags: voltage, battery-charging, piezoelectricity

I am currently working on a project in which I am using piezoelectric material to charge a battery. The voltage output of the piezoelectric material is variable depending on how much mechanical energy is applied to it. I don't want there to be too much voltage or it will fry the battery, and if there is too little, the battery won't charge well. I am using a 9V battery. How can I limit the voltage input to not be too high or too low?

Comment: simplistic suggestion: how about a zener regulator?  it's just a zener diode to clamp the voltage, and a resistor to limit the current once the zener starts conducting.

Comment: How much voltage and current are you realistically expecting to get from this piezoelectric material?

Comment: The piezos I have come across so far usually are quite high impedance. Without a proper harvesting circuit I doubt you will get anything usable into a battery if you just connect it with some voltage protection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using a buck boost converter circuit. I am posting this schematic only as an example. This IC can take only 5.5V as input voltage, so use this just to get an idea.[image]

Comment: And a piezoelectric source will drive that without any problem, will it?

Comment: More mechanical energy gives an high voltage right? So if it exceeds the 5.5V it will damage the chip.